# Compare 2 dates with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to compare two dates with a payment condition:

1. Date 1: invoice date
2. Date 2: payment date
3. Payment condition in days

I want to calculate if a payment was done within or without the payment condition. What I tried so far, but without the expected results.

```
SELECT
(
CASE 
    WHEN  ISNUMERIC(a.paymentcondition) >=  DATEDIFF(day,a.payment_date,a.invoice_date) 
    THEN 'yes' 
    ELSE 'no' 
END) 
AS 'within_payment_condition'
FROM finance
```

Comment: Remove `ISNUMERIC`, because it returns only `0` or `1`. If you want to convert use `CAST`. Anyway as always you should prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data and desired results. `"but without the expected results"` is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a table called `test1` as following :

```
create table test1 (id int, date1 date, date2 date);
insert into test1 values (1, '2015-04-06', '2015-04-05'), (2, '2015-06-06', '2015-06-07');
```

Then you can compare dates using the following query:

```
select *, 

case 
when test1.date1 < test1.date2 then 'test1 is smaller' 
else 'test1 is not smaller' 
end as comment

from test1
```

Result will be like this:

[image]